# How to know if someone has read a post based on time to read

Tags: javascript, php, post, time, delay

So I want to know if its possible to store into database whoever reads a post. I know it's easy but here is the real process. Every post has a time to read(i.e 4 mins to read...). whoever enters the post page, I check the database if the user has read that article already or not. if not, i want to take the user id and article id and add it to the table, but only after a cetain amount of time has passed based on the time to read of each post. For example if a post is 5 mins to read and the user hasnt read the post before, i want to add his info to the table after 5 mins. Is this possible? Here is what I tried:

So first of all i tried the sleep function but didnt work cause it would tdelay the page loading and didnt work. I dont know if it's right or not but i did something like this :

```
$seconds = $time *60000; // converts minute to miliseconds. 
if($post_data){
  $check = new post();
   $result = $check->checkreader($userid,$articleid);
   if($result){
//user has read the post
   }else{
    sleep($seconds);
    $check->addreader($id, $articleid);
  }
```

the addreader and checkreader are functions inside a class (post) which check and insert the data into the database.
I also tried the Java script set timout method but still didnt work. Most of the time, the function worked but the delay didnt work.

```
$seconds = $time * 60000;// converts minute to miliseconds. 
if($post_data){
  $check = new post();
   $result = $check->checkreader($userid,$articleid);
   if($result){
//user has read the post
   }else{
    echo "<script>
     setTimeout(function(){".
      $check->addreader( $id, $articleid)
     .";}, $seconds);
    </script>";
}
```

I want to do this so it could be a real reading system. if a reader spends the specified amount of time on a post, he has read it or else not. This way users cant just open a post and spam read everything.
is there a simpler way or at leasta possible way?

Comment: I think you'll need a javascript timer of xmin and send a Ajax request

Comment: As @executable says, you would need to use Ajax requests. PHP is executed before page load and scripts after page load will be in JavaScript. You'll need to create some kind of simple API for what you want to achieve

Comment: You could check if they scroll down to the end of the article as well (also using JS). If they are on the page without scrolling down to the end of the article, I wouldn't call it "read", no matter how many minutes has passed by.

Comment: That's a good point. A combination of realistic words per minute and scrolling would probably be the best solution

Comment: Short answer: you won't be able to it with just PHP. PHP would just render the page and does not run in real time. 
The solution to your problem would require using an asynchronous way to store that information, such as javascript asynchronous requests (ajax).
More details here : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Fetching_data

Comment: I have completely no experience with Ajax but thanks, i will try to find a solution for it. As for M. Eriksson's suggestion, I think it is a great way to do it but i dont seem to figure  out a way to do it. I am running a php query with a javascript function and I think for the query to be executed that way, I need to pass the info within the javascript to another page. is that right?